# Why users should solve the problem of spam by solving capchas?

Tags: captcha, spam, honeypot-captcha

Why the problem of spam should be solved by users?

Why user should prove that he is not spammer?

Maybe it would be better for spammers to prove that he is real user?

Having javascript on the client is already a proof that user is not spammer.
Spam bots haven't javascript because it is not a regular browsers.

**Maybe it would be better for user experience to generate question and answer it with javascript instead of user?**

Spam protection could be like invisible capcha.

Comment: This seems like more of a discussion topic than an actual answerable User Experience question. I don't understand your bold piece here - better UX to generate question and answer it with javascript instead of user? What do you mean here?

Comment: In the world of UX, I think we all completely agree with you. CAPTCHAs are evil and asking users to solve a problem that should be better handled via the technology is a poor direction.

Comment: @DA01: there IS a limited number of situations where captchas can be appropriate. Once I was designing a registration form for a university's Masters program. The program required entrance exams, one of which was Math. So I decided to implement my captcha as a randomly generated math problem (to give a sense what's coming ahead). Solution required Taylor expansions up to 3rd order. It was fun! And students liked it (those who passed at least). Unfortunately, word spread out and some folks started registering just to see if they can solve "the crazy captcha", so the idea was abandoned >.>

Comment: @JonW In bold part I mean "maybe it is better for user to solve captcha instead of the user?"

Answer (score 2):

Your question is better addressed to the `security` forum. I believe they have discussed CAPTCHAs at length, for example check the following post: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29571/is-there-a-true-alternative-to-using-captcha-images

And your premise that spammers don't have Javascript is also incorrect. There is a number of projects (eg [SeleniumHQ](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)) which allows you to access browser's capabilities, including running the Javascript on the page.